# Is a future event fixed by happening of past events?

Tags: determinism

If i say an event as an outcome of past events and those past events as outcomes of earlier events. I can also say that an event generates future event. If i take all the systems of chains of events and say all the interacts among them generates
future events; fixed reactions getting fixed results; would i be right?

Comment: This is called "determinism" and was the approach to science up to the 19th century, when Statistical Mechanics was born. We now know that Nature sometimes can only be described by using probability, so future can't be predicted precisely! The advent of Quantum Mechanics confirmed this point of view.

Answer (score -1):

Future is indeed an outcome of past events. But considering this very moment as the precursor to the upcoming future events, there can be infinitely many futures owing to small differences in god knows how many variables. According to QM, every future happens parallely. From this moment onwards, we have added infinitely many pathways to our future. So as time passes, the complexity grows. Let's say there is an end to time and when that happens, all these pathways converge into one last ending. You can't isolate any one event to predict it's future alone. A moment in the entirety (I don't use the word universe because it doesn't capture my imagination of everything. There is still a lot left to discover) can be pictured as a 3-D (or, maybe more dimensions) snapshot of all it's constituents. Each and every constituent is linked and the future of any single element can't be purely it's own. It's a collective future. If you posses the value of all the variables then no one can stop you from exactly predicting the future. However, future is dynamic and it changes spontaneously with whatever we do presently. Immediate future is a fixed event w.r.t the immediate past.